# How can I write a hash function which returns a string?

Tags: javascript, hash, url-shortener

I have been trying to solve [URL Shortener](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5fee4559135609002c1a1841/train/javascript) question on Codewars but I have been unable to pass the test cases. My solution is getting timed out. I cannot find a fast efficient way of hashing which returns a string. Most algorithms that I found are returning an integer after hashing a string. The shortened URL should consist only of lowercase letters.

**My solution**

```js
const map = new Map();
const longToShortURL = new Map();
let url = 'short.ly/';
    
const urlShortener = (longURL) => {
    if (longToShortURL.has(longURL)) return url + longToShortURL.get(longURL);
    
    const letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    let key = getKey(letters);
    while (map.has(key)) {
        key = getKey(letters);
    }
    
    map.set(key, longURL);
    longToShortURL.set(longURL, key);
    return url + key;
};
const getRandomInt = (max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
};
    
const getKey = (letters) => {
    let key = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        key += letters.charAt(getRandomInt(letters.length));
    }
    return key;
};

const urlRedirector = (shortURL) => {
    const key = shortURL.split(url)[1];
    return map.get(key);
};
```

**Result**

```
Passed: 2 Failed: 0 Exit Code: 1
Test Results:
Should pass all of these
Testing two different URLs
Testing same URLs
Completed in 1ms
Strict tests
STDERR
Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)
```

Why did my code time out?

Our servers are configured to only allow a certain amount of time for your code to execute. In rare cases the server may be taking on too much work and simply wasn't able to run your code efficiently enough. Most of the time though this issue is caused by inefficient algorithms. If you see this error multiple times you should try to optimize your code further.

Comment: I don't see any hashing in your code. You're generating a random key for a URL and storing it in the map. You should use one of the various hashing functions out there. Btw, what test case failed exactly?

Comment: Insead of doing `let var = ...` then a `while` use `do ... while` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/do...while
Maybe you can earn time by using a plain object insead of a Map

Comment: the shortened URL should consist of lowercase letters only. Hash functions available are returning an integer after hashing. I want to get a string with lowercase letters